# How do I listen on all array items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, dom-events

I am collecting all images elements  from the document `var listen = document.getElementsByTagName('img');` which results in an array. Now I have to specify `listen[0]`, `listen[1]`, `listen[2]`, `listen[3]` etc to listen for events on a element from this array. The question is is there any way to just do something like `listen[any item from this array]`, or a function. Just to don't have to specify every element to listen on manually.

#### Example

Now I have to do something like this, for every array item:
`listen[3].click = function() {};`

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about event delegation.

Comment: [getElementsByTagName(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: I am thankfull for any sources and explanations, thank you.

Comment: Use a loop... move it into a reusable function.

Comment: @Kay I don't see a difference.

Comment: @amnotiam Is that the most efficient way to solve it?

Comment: @user2162852: Efficient it what way?

Comment: @user2162852 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects

Comment: @amnotiam if I could just loop this HTMLCollection one time and add to my object event listeners for every item of this HTMLCollection, I would don't, have to loop every time.

Comment: @user2162852 I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: You would loop once and assign the handler. If you're creating new `img` elements in the future, you'd assign the handler directly when they're created,.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help, I think I can handle it from now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what it is exactly what you want and what the DOM looks like you may want to use an event listener higher up the DOM tree somewhere instead of create a lot of listeners:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName !== 'IMG') {
        return;
    }

    alert('img clicked');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/APSMT/1/

*Note that I have attached the event listener to `document`, but if you can make it more specific you should*

Answer (score 1):

With a reasonable new browser you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function (img) {
    el.addEventListener('click', callback);
});
```

Or "old skool" (and maybe even better readable):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; ++i) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click', callback);
}
```

Reading the `HTMLCollection.length` only once can give a speed-up. It will never be slower.

You should not create a Function object for every iteration:

```
// Don't
for (...) {
    img[i].onclick = function () { ... }
}

// Do
function onclick () {
     // `this` will be img[i]
}
for (...) {
    img[i].onclick = onclick;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, all examples and explanations appreciated.