# getElementsByName returns nodelist or htmlcollection

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

Totally new to javascript. Ran a getElementsByName query and got a nodelist, however I was looking for an htmlcollection. I know this is due to Dom level implementation.

Qustion: 
Should I be testing for a return type to be sure or is there a better way of assuring the outcome?

Comment: getElementsByName() returns a HTMLCollection of all the elements with a given value for the name attribute.

Comment: An HTMLCollection is a list of nodes. Collections in the HTML DOM are assumed to be live meaning that they are automatically updated when the underlying.    The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes, without defining or constraining how this collection is implemented. NodeList objects in the DOM are live.

Comment: According to the spec I found, it is supposed to return a NodeList http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259

Comment: Same for DOM Level 1 : http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-A6C9094

Comment: @Teemu: An `HTMLCollection` provides additional methods. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15763707/218196.

Comment: *" Should I be testing for a return type to be sure or is there a better way of assuring the outcome?"* Why do you want an `HTMLCollection` anyway? You are probably better off sticking to the `NodeList` interface.

Comment: @FelixKling Now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNodeList(nodes) {
 var result = Object.prototype.toString.call(nodes);
 if (typeof nodes === 'object' && /^\[object HTMLCollection|NodeList|Object)\]$/.test(result) && nodes.hasOwnProperty('length') && (nodes.length == 0 || (typeof nodes[0] === "object" && nodes[0].nodeType > 0))) {
  return true;
 }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: (I think) the problem is if you're doing that on a node list in a different frame, it won't have the NodeList inheritance of the other frame. Same thing with `list instanceof Array`. That's why it's always good to use the Object's toString method.