# jQuery.each does not seem to work

Tags: jquery

I have a rather bizarre situation where I am trying to iterate through check boxes using `each`. Problem is it does not want to go in the loop.

Please advise as to why?

This is the function

```
function AddTheProduct() {
    var txtTopicsGuids = "";

    var checkedTopics = document.getElementsByName("chkRelatedTopics");
    $(checkedTopics).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //action
        }
    });
```

and the markup

```html
{{each Items}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='hidTopicsDomain' value='${DomainObjectKey}'/>
            <input type='checkbox' name='chkRelatedTopics' value='${subject}'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I think you should use `$.each` here.

Comment: They do the same thing.

Comment: What does `console.log(checkedTopics.length);` give you?

Comment: Why do you think its doesn't access the loop?

Comment: @Ram: No, `checkedTopics` should be a `NodeList`, because `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ did you consider the case where the checkboxes are not checked?

Comment: **Aside:** if you have no `else` condition then consider being more specific in your selector. `$('input[name=chkRelatedTopics]:checked').each( ...`

Comment: Nice docs for you (just in case): http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/template-tag-each

Comment: @FelixKling, `document.getElementsByName()` returns an  `HTMLCollection` not a `NodeList`.

Comment: @Arianule - Was this issue reproducible in multiple browsers? There are bugs specific to the returned object type for `getElementsByName` and certain browsers. Since Matias was able to use the sample code in a fiddle, perhaps it's not elsewhere in your code but in your test environment.

Comment: @Anthony: Actually that differs from browser to browser. The `HTMLCollection` interface is a super set of the `NodeList` interface, so it doesn't really matter (FWIW, according to the DOM2 specification the method should return a `NodeList`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects/15763707#15763707).

Comment: @FelixKling - Pistols at dawn it is. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code should work. I think the problem has nothing to do with the `$.each` method but with something else.

[Here is a simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/pYd6b/) of your code I recreated in jsFiddle.

Either the problem is in your template or somewhere else. Also, take into account the advice given in the other answers in terms of best practices, primarily make use of the appropriate selectors instead of doing `getElementsByName` and then wrapping that in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function AddTheProduct() {
   var txtTopicsGuids = "";
   $("input[name=chkRelatedTopics]").each(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          //action
       }

   });
}
```

Comment: there is no comparison between javascript and jquery. So, "_You are using javascript and jQuery mixeup_" doesn't make sense. I think so.

Comment: @Mr_Green The OP is using the object created by javscript and then in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input[name="chkRelatedTopics"]').each(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
//do something here
}
});
```