# getElementsByTagName() method doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to simply change the text inside all `</p>` elements with this code

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p></p>
    <script>
        elem=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        elem.innerHTML="work";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

from this I expect `work` to appear on the page, but the result is just a blank page with no text. why?

Comment: FIrst of all getByTagName returns you an array of results, not a single element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> getElementsByTagName is method of the DOM interface. It accepts a tag
>   name as input and returns a NodeList (some browsers chose to return
>   HTMLCollection instead, which is OK, since it is a superset of
>   NodeList).
>
> [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

You have to set the index of your HTMLCollection/NodeList.

```
elem=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
elem[0].innerHTML="work";
```

You can also do it for each `p` tag in your HTML document.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var index = 0; index < elem.length; index++){
    elem[index].innerHTML="work";
}
```

Comment: Well, actually its not an array but a HTMLCollection. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

It returns a `NodeList` which you need to loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML="work";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it returns list of elements

if you have one then you might use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
```

if you want to apply it to multiple

then you have to iterate over the list

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('p')    
for(index in list){
  list[index].innerHTML = 'work';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jquery included you can do it as following:

```
$("p").text("work");
or better


$(document).ready(function(){

$("p").text("work");/*when the dom of the page is fully loaded text  inside p tags will be changed to "work"*/
});
```

That way you have a faster cross browser sollution