# HTMLCollection Length does not match logged object

Tags: javascript

```
// Find all posts
var posts = node.getElementsByClassName("userContentWrapper");
var post, text;
console.log(posts);
console.log(typeof(posts));
console.log(Object.keys(posts));
console.log(posts.length);
```

The above outputs:
[image]

:( I don't understand. Why is length 0? It works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7yfv37s/

I also printed the object again after the length, and it still shows length: 4. [image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'll give it a shot. Give me a few minutes. It seems to work properly in a jsFiddle. :( http://jsfiddle.net/p7yfv37s/

Comment: @Donal I'm not sure what you mean. How does that affect what .length logs compared to what the object logs.

Comment: The DOM can't be magically updated between two lines of JS code. That's why I asked for a fiddle.

Comment: I voted to close for "no reproduction". @sihrc I suggest your delete your question and make a new one if you find the conditions of reproduction (and don't find the explanation on your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your cursor over the **i** icon you will see that `HtmlCollection` state is captured only upon first expansion. It does not show its state at the moment of `console.log` invocation.

[image]

Most likely logging is performed before DOM is loaded or `node` is dynamically populated by javascript. `HTMLCollection` is kind of *live* collection which track all DOM changes ([more info about difference between `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects))

See simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/p7yfv37s/1/

Comment: Is the way around this then to use some sort of callback?

Comment: Yes, but I can't give more info since your question does not provide details about what is causing DOM changes.

Comment: It's the Facebook feed. I have a mutation observer on the news feed and I want to capture posts as they populate to do some analysis.