# How to get multiple div id using queryselectorAll method

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a functionality on click event.
I want to display none four div but this code seems doesn't work for me 
Please tell me the mistake in this

```
<a class="lightbox-close" href="#" onclick="document.querySelectorAll('#goofy_1,#goofy_2,#goofy_3,#goofy_4').style.display = 'none';"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query selector is not like jQuery selector where you can do

```
$('#goofy_1,#goofy_2,#goofy_3,#goofy_4')// it will get you all div selected
```

Instead Query selector returns [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which means you are getting

try console log your `querySelectorAll`

```
 console.log( querySelectorAll('#goofy_1,#goofy_2,#goofy_3,#goofy_4'));
```

you will get something like

*i.e* i am selecting a

> [image]

now you can see that there isnt single element selected so you can directly make any changes

Now you need to loop through all element like ***Arun P Johny*** telling

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('#goofy_1,#goofy_2,#goofy_3,#goofy_4');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    allElements [i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Good Read

[Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

The [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you need to iterate over it and set the properties.

So it will be better to write a separate function where you can write the iteration logic

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#goofy_1,#goofy_2,#goofy_3,#goofy_4');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```