# Why forEach array method is not a function on looping over document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

In order to get the matched elements & loop over it , I am using  `querySelectorAll` & `forEach` array method. According to [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),`querySelectorAll` will return a `nodelist`.

I can also use `getElementsByClassName` by get the matched elements but cannot directly use `forEach`. But [**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) link tell us that it also return an nodelist object

on using `forEach` on return of `getElementsByClassName` it throws an error ,`forEach is not a function`

Can you please let me know why `forEach` does not directly work on return of `getElementsByClassName`, when return of both `getElementsByClassName` & `querySelectorAll` is `nodelist`

Comment: `forEach` is an Array method, not a NodeList one?

Comment: @krzyk this is more a conceptual question .Still you can refer this https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ocju73p7/1/ 
You need to replace with querySelectorAll with getElementsByClass to see the error

Comment: Don't rely on W3Schools to completely correct information. `getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: @Bergi It works on NodeList.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Ah, right, it's one of the new DOM4 methods.

Answer (score 5):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` not an `Array`. Never fear, tho!

You can use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to change the context of the `Array.prototype.forEach` function.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'gold', 'lawngreen', 'dodgerblue', 'deepskyblue', 'blueviolet'];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(elem, idx) {
  // do something
  elem.style.color = colors[idx];
});
```

```html
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
<span>D</span>
<span>E</span>
<span>F</span>
<span>G</span>
```

---

**EDIT**

> Actually my doubt is why `forEach` does not directly work on return of `document.getElementsByClassName`

That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` reutrns an `HTMLCollection` not an `Array`. `HTMLCollection` does not have a `forEach` method on its prototype.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
console.log(nodes.constructor.name);
//=> HTMLCollection
```

```html
<span>A</span>
```

Comment: Actually my doubt is why forEach does not directly work on return of document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2):

From what I tested:

```
<ul>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elementList = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    console.log(elementList.constructor);
    var elementList2 = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    console.log(elementList2);
    console.log(elementList2.constructor);
</script>
```

`querySelectorAll` returns:

```
NodeList() { [native code] }
```

while `getElementsByClassName` returns:

```
HTMLCollection() { [native code] }
```

Pretty much, as the previous answer mentioned, the HTML collection doesn't have access to the forEach method.

EDIT1: [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects) seems to answer some of the differences!

EDIT2: It seems like you can iterate through an HTML Collection with the technique using ES6 mentioned here: [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Answer (score 0):

We can interact with an HTML Collection as if it’s an array in many other ways. We can use index numbers to access data. It looks like an array. But it functions a bit differently. First of all, a bit of a distinction. I’ve heard nodeList and HTMLCollection used somewhat interchangeably. They’re both DOM lists, but the only real difference is that HTMLCollection is more specific. It contains DOM elements that are the same, whereas a nodeList can contain a variety of DOM elements. That’s why querySelectorAll returns a nodeList but getElementsByTagName returns an HTMLCollection. Interestingly enough, forEach works on a nodeList but not an HTMLCollection.

Now there are a number of ways to iterate over a HTMLCollection;

1. `var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p") for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { console.log(p)}`
   Check other ways here https://medium.com/@larry.sassainsworth/iterating-over-an-html-collection-in-javascript-5071f58fad6b