# Modify/Update element styles in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I modify/update elements with unique class name in JavaScript?

The following code is not working:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

HTML markup:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.test')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.test')`

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, so you'll have to pluck out individual elements, or iterate through the whole thing!

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, so you need to specify which of the matching elements will have the style applied to it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jnu44ck0/

Comment: Array != HTMLcollection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects