# Best practice to select an event target with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

#### Problem:

1. Whenever user clicks on column's header in table, a classname `.active` from all the same `table tr th span.sorting` shoud have been removed.
2. Add a classname `.active` to the child of currently clicked target element.

#### Structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span class="sorting"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="sorting"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span class="sorting active"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Solution (already done):

1. *don't know*
2. To add a class to a child of clicked column: `trigger.target.children[0].classList.add('active')`

What is the best way to remove all `active` classes from `<span class="sorting">` whenever I click on the `<th>` element and assign an `active` class to currently clicked block?

No jQuery, please.

Comment: Please share a working snippet using `<>` demonstrating your issue.

Comment: *What is the best way to remove all classes from `<span class="sorting">`* You want to remove classes or elements with class `sorting`?

Comment: you want to remove class sorting or active?

Comment: @gurvinder372 - will do a jsfiddle in a moment, and sorry I forgot to say "remove all active classes", I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to fetch elements and `Array.from` to transform the output to array.

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "th .sorting" ) );
```

Now iterate them and remove the class using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) APIs

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "th .sorting" ) ).forEach( function( ele ){
  ele.classList.remove( "active" );
});
```

finally to the current element you can add the class to `currentTarget` of the event

```
event.currentTarget.classList.add( "active" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var elements = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "th .sorting" ));

elements.forEach( function(ele){
   ele.addEventListener( "click", function(){
      elements.forEach( function( ele ){
         ele.classList.remove( "active" );
      });
      ele.classList.add( "active" );
   });
});
```

```css
.active
{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting">A</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting">B</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting active">C</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: One question - why you didn't used DOM HTMLCollection, but querySelector instead ? 
Thank you for your anwer.

Comment: `querySelectorAll`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll returns NodeList only.. Check this to see the difference between NodeList and HTMLCollection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the class active on click of a `.sorting` element, then add on the currentTarget

```js
let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sorting'));
elements.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', s => {
    elements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    s.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  });
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting"></span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting"></span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting active"></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you are adding an `addEventListener`, why it couldn't be done without it, directly ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allTh = document.querySelectorAll("#tbl thead tr th");
for(var i = 0; i < allTh.length; i++){
  allTh[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
      removeAllActiveClasses();
      e.target.classList.add("active");
  });
}

function removeAllActiveClasses(){
  var allActiveClassElement = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
  for(var i = 0; i < allActiveClassElement.length; i++){
    allActiveClassElement[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.active{
  color : blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>
              <span class="sorting">Col 1</span>
              
          </th>
          <th>
              <span class="sorting">Col 2</span>
              
          </th>
          <th>
              <span class="sorting active">Col 3</span>
          </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".active.sorting").forEach(e=>e.classList.remove("active"))
event.currentTarget.classList.add(".active")
```

we have forEach function on value returned from querySelector, so we can iterate over that domArray, then the second code line is to be placed in context on event listener

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Working directly on HTMLCollection should also be a possible way to go:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sorting');
for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    elements[i].className -= ' active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```js
var elems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("sorting"));
//console.log(elems)
elems.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  elems.forEach(e => e.classList.remove("active"))
  event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}));
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px verdana
}

span.active {
  color: red;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting">One</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting">Two</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span class="sorting active">Three</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why is there an `addEventListener` ? It works without it, but why you have included it ? does it have some specific purpose ?

Comment: You are trying to change the class on `click` event, so you have to add a EventListener for click @aspirinemaga