# how do I select only the odd or even variables that used in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

here's my JS code:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('box').length ;i++) {
//code here
}
```

I'm wondering how to select only the odd or even i's

Comment: Use javascript's mod operator (%) and divide by 2 in your loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: Another approach would be to calculate `i % 2` and check for `0` or `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Array operation map

```
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    boxes.forEach(function(box, index) {
       if (index % 2 === 0) {
         //even elements are here, you can access it by box
       } else {
         //odd elements are here, you can access it by box
       }
    });
```

Or simple loop

```
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('box').length ;i++) {
  if ( i % 2 === 0) { even }
  else { odd }
}
```

**Update**

as @Motti said, .map, forEach (or any Array operation) won't work on HTMLCollection, what you may need to do is:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(boxes).forEach(function(box, index){
    if (index % 2 === 0) { //even box }
    else { //odd box }
 })
```

Comment: Yes It should be forEach loop.

Comment: `HTMLCollection` is not an array, it has `length` but no `forEach` or `map` functions.

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the whole collection, instead do: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxes,...`

Answer (score 4):

Even numbers have this odd property (even odd numbers do) that adding two to them keeps them even (or odd).

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i += 2) {} // even 
for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i += 2) {} // odd
```

Note, if there's no good reason to evaluate `getElementByClassName` over and over again I would move it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Like @stvnBrkdll said

```
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('box').length ;i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {} // this are the even no.s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better that you use `querySelectorAll()` instead, details on [**NodeLists** and **Live HTMLCollections**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763707/2813224). And **[use `let` instead of `var`](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/)**.

The easiest way to determine if a loop is currently on an even or odd iteration is by using the modulus of 2:

```
if ( i % 2 === 0) {
 ... // do whatever for even counts
} else {
 ...// otherwise it's an odd iteration if it isn't even
}
```

### Demo

```js
var NodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for (let i=0; i<NodeList.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    NodeList[i].textContent +="\nEVEN";
  } else {
    NodeList[i].textContent +="\nODD";
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>BOX</div><b>The count starts at 0 so second box is odd. This can easily be adjusted at the for loop</b>
<div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div><div class='box'>BOX</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}

for (var i=0;i<ocument.getElementsByClassName('box').length;i++) {
 if(isOdd(i))
 {
  // Code goes here when i is odd
 }
 else
 {
  // Code goes here when i is even
 }
}
```