# What type of data does querySelectorAll return?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

A javaScript object does not have a length property, but the returned value of `querySelectorAll` has a length property, indicating that it's an array. But if we check it by `Array.isArray()` then it returns false, proving that it is not an array. What type of data is it then?

```js
var obj1 = {
  fname: "Mirajul",
  lname: "Momin",
  age: 24
};
console.log(obj1.length);
var paraList = document.querySelectorAll("p");
console.log(paraList.length);
console.log(Array.isArray(paraList));
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph one</p>
<p>This is paragraph two</p>
<p>This is paragraph three</p>
<p>This is paragraph four</p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Element method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

For the differences please visit: [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

You can use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make that as an array:

```js
var obj1 = {
  fname: "Mirajul",
  lname: "Momin",
  age: 24
};
console.log(obj1.length);
var paraList = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];
console.log(paraList.length);
console.log(Array.isArray(paraList));
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph one</p>
<p>This is paragraph two</p>
<p>This is paragraph three</p>
<p>This is paragraph four</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation, "A non-live `NodeList` containing one `Element` object for each element that matches at least one of the specified selectors or an empty `NodeList` in case of no matches."

You can check more about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll() returns an array of objects with the elements that match the specified group of selectors.

.isArray() will return false because it returns object not array

Syntax:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('selectors');
```

- 'selectors' is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.
- elms is an array with the selected HTML elements.

Example, gets an Array with the content of LI tags with class='sites', and the tags with class='note' within element with id='dv1', then it displays their content:

Read the blog to better understand the querySelectorAll

https://coursesweb.net/javascript/queryselector-queryselectorall