# Why is my .parentNode returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I´m trying to make a simple To-do List, and I want it to have a button to add the tasks that I want and another button to remove all tasks but when I click the delete button I get an error: "Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined" I don´t know why it says the parentNode is undefined.
Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>To do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>To-do List</h1>
        <div id="form">
            <input type="text" name="" id="tarefa" value="Add an item!">
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            <button id="delete">Clear List</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <ul id="lista">
            <li id="112">Test1</li>
            <li>Test2</li>
        </ul>
    </main>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//Javascript file
const tarefa = document.getElementById("tarefa")
const adicionar = document.getElementById("submit")
const limpar = document.getElementById("delete")
const padre = document.getElementById("lista")
const fpp = document.querySelectorAll("li") 

//Add the tasks
function enviar(e){
    var coisa = document.createElement("li")
    let escrito = tarefa.value;
    padre.appendChild(coisa)
    coisa.innerHTML = escrito
    
}
//Delete the tasks
function apagar(e){
    fpp.parentNode.removeChild(fpp)
    console.log("aaaa")
}

adicionar.addEventListener("click",enviar)
limpar.addEventListener("click",apagar)
```

Comment: so where is `fds` defined? `fpp` is a HTML Collection, there is no parentNode on an HTML collection.

Comment: Maybe your `const fpp = document.querySelectorAll("li")` is running before the dom is finished loading and it needs to be called in an `onload` function.

Comment: Actually `.querySelectorAll()` returns a list, not one element. So `.parentElement` should never work there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128519/what-type-of-data-does-queryselectorall-return

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` (because you're selecting all `li` tags, not just one), so you need to do a forEach loop. Give the context, I asume `fds` is supposed to be `fpp` (you never define `fds` in the code you provided), so here is the code you would need, given that assumption:

```js
function apagar(e){
  fpp.forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
  })
}
```

---

### Update

Use this so that you dont get null errors once the list is deleted the first time.

```js
function apagar(e){
  document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
  })
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying: Unexpected token '>'

Comment: @AndréSantos Yes, I accidentally used a technique from a different version of JS, I made an edit a bit ago to do it correctly

Comment: So now instead of undifined it says null -> "Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null"

Comment: Correct, given your code, you only grab the `li` elements, so once they are deleted, you will get an error. I have provided another snippet to take care of that problem by grabbing all the `li` elements each time the button is clicked

Comment: for some reason, this worked for me, where `for ... in` did not (the `element.parentNode`s were undefined).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function apagar(){
  padre.innerHTML = "";
}
```