# How to read a value of a selected element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have several images like this:

```
    <img id="geqfader" frequency="100" src="img/fader.png" />
    <img id="geqfader" frequency="400" src="img/fader.png" />
    <img id="geqfader" frequency="1600" src="img/fader.png" />
    <img id="geqfader" frequency="6300" src="img/fader.png" />
```

When the user clicks on an image, I want to invoke a function and pass on the value of `frequency`:

```
  document.getElementById('geqfader').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showResult(hereIWantTheFrequencyValue, toneFrequency)
  });
```

How can I pass the image `frequency` value into `showResult` (where `hereIWantTheFrequencyValue` is)?

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_. Use a class instead. `frequency` should be `data-frequency` to produce valid markup. Then use `querySelectorAll()` or `getElementsByClassName()` to get the elements and `this` and `dataset` in the event handler to get the value.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I'll consider using another attribute then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML the `id` value should be unique value for each element. In situation like yours, you can use a custom attribute on your elements. To get the element using your custom attribute you can use `querySelectorAll` function in JavaScript as shown in the following example:

```js
let elms = document.querySelectorAll('[my_id="geqfader"]');

for(let elm of elms){
elm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('frequency'))
  });
}
```

```html
<img my_id="geqfader" frequency="100" src="img/fader.png" />
<img my_id="geqfader" frequency="400" src="img/fader.png" />
<img my_id="geqfader" frequency="1600" src="img/fader.png" />
<img my_id="geqfader" frequency="6300" src="img/fader.png" />
```

**EDIT** 
As an alternative I suggest you to use the `class` attribute instead of a custom attribute which allows you to use the `getElementsByClassName` function instead of `querySelectorAll`. Also, the `data-` prefix gives us the ability to use custom data attributes.

```js
let elms = document.getElementsByClassName('geqfader');

for(let elm of elms){
elm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('frequency'))
  });
}
```

```html
<img class="geqfader" data-frequency="100" src="img/fader.png" />
<img class="geqfader" data-frequency="400" src="img/fader.png" />
<img class="geqfader" data-frequency="1600" src="img/fader.png" />
<img class="geqfader" data-frequency="6300" src="img/fader.png" />
```

Comment: @Andreas just in case that maybe in some situation new attributes would be needed( i tried to answer question in more general form. but you are right and i personally prefer to use class instead, so i will edit my answer and will mention this approach).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. What is the reason for using a `for` loop? Can't I just use `.addEventListener` on `document.getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: your welcome, `getElementsByClassName()` will return array of elements so you have to loop throughout all of your elements and attach event listener to them.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is certainly correct, but I find the other answer that uses `onclick` in the img tag easier to use as a beginner. I wish I could accept more than one answer ...

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `HTMLCollection` which is an array-like structure but not an actual array.

Comment: @Max I would go with this one (or even better use event delegation if there's a common parent element) - [javascript - Why Should I Avoid Inline Scripting? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)

Comment: _"it will needed you to use `getElementsByClassName` function instead of `querySelectorAll` in order to retrieview elements"_ - No id doesn't. `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` work with css selectors -> `document.querySelectorAll(".geqfader")`

Comment: @Andreas which one would be preferred - `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`? In case it influences the decision, I might add `<p class="geqfader">x Hz</p>` later on, depending on how the lay-out will turn out.

Comment: @Max The `.querySelector` methods work with css selectors, hence you can get anything you want with them - as long as there's a valid selector for it. With the "older" `.getElements...` methods you will have to decide first if you're looking for a tagname, a class or a name. And the methods have different return values ([NodeList vs. HTMLCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)), which can make your life easier or more complicated. Check their documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right but for `class` selector, `getElementsByClassName` is faster than `querySelectorAll` (At least in chrome browser).

Comment: Care to explain why you think it is "faster"? And even if this would be the case, that's unnecessary micro-optimisation. Use whatever makes your life easier.

Comment: @Andreas [Here is the reason](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/25)

Answer (score 1):

replace all ids with class and set `onclick="showValue(this)"` to all img tags like code below...

```
        <img class="geqfader" onclick="showValue(this)" frequency="100" src="img/fader.png" />
        <img class="geqfader" onclick="showValue(this)" frequency="400" src="img/fader.png" />
        <img class="geqfader" onclick="showValue(this)" frequency="1600" src="img/fader.png" />
        <img class="geqfader" onclick="showValue(this)" frequency="6300" src="img/fader.png" />


<script>

function showValue(img){
  alert(img.getAttribute('frequency'));
}

</script>
```

Comment: This was by far the easiest working solution, but I accepted the other answer to have better separation between HTML & JavaScript. If I could accept multiple answers, I would also accept this one!

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more JavaScript and understand how the DOM and EventListener works.
First of all IDs are unique, even if you can define duplicates its invalid markup.
`document.getElementById` returns only the first matched element so your click handler is only attached to the first img.
This should work:

```
Array.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img[frequency]")).forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var frequency = e.target.getAttribute("frequency");
  });
});
```

`Array.slice.call` is used because `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` and not an `Array`

Answer (score -1):

`event.target.getAttribute('frequency')`

Where `event` is the argument that the event handler function takes as argument.

Comment: `event.target === this` but this won't work either as the event handler only would be added to the first image.