# How to sum elements dynamically added with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am adding table rows dynamically to a table using Javascript.

Is there a reason why `items.length` doesn't increase when I add a row?

I am also trying to sum the numbers contained in each row. But this doesn't work either. The dynamically added rows are completely ignored for some reason.

I am coming from jQuery where things like these used to work.

I am probably missing something really fundamental here. Thanks for any pointers.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var form = document.querySelector("#form");
  var items = form.querySelectorAll(".item");

  form.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.className == ".add_item") {
      addFields(event);
    }
  });

  function addFields(event) {
    var item = document.createElement("template");
    item.innerHTML = fields.trim();
    items[items.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", item.content.firstChild);
    console.log(items.length);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

})
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList`. Just check it out 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only query the items once here:

```
var items = form.querySelectorAll(".item");

form.addEventListener(
  //you call addItem here
)

function addItem(){
  //you access items.length here
}
```

You need to keep re-query-ing the selectors every time you add an item.

```
var items = form.querySelectorAll(".item"); //i got queried for the 1st time

function addFields(event) {
  items = form.querySelectorAll(".item"); //get items again

  //...
}
```

Or just don't query outside `addFields()` all in all. Put `var items = ...` in the function. There's no need to put it outside.

Read up @Rajesh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58097473/7325182) why this is so.

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) where as `getElementsByClassName` returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

The difference is, NodeList is a static copy but HTMLCollection is a live copy. So if element is modified, like in your case, a new row is added, HTMLCollection will work but NodeList will not.

So changing

```
var items = form.querySelectorAll(".item")
```

to

```
var items = form.getElementsByClassName("item")
```

might solve the problem.

**Pointers**

- You cannot have a selector in `getElementsByClassName`. It expects a className, you cannot use composite selector like `#form .item`.

#### Reference:

- [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)