# Why does document.querySelector return an Element while document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList

Tags: javascript

The docs say that `document.querySelector` return an `Element` while `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. Why is this discrepancy there? Why `document.querySelectorAll` return an `Element` array?

Note: The question tagged as duplicate of this isn't answering my question that why `document.querySelectorAll` does not return an `Element` array? on the same lines as `document.querySelector` return an `Element. The former is just plural of the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: If you only need or expect one why would you need a collection? Answer seems fairly obvious here

Comment: Are you asking about the discrepancy between `Node` and `Element`, or [the discrepancy between single values and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/1048572)?

Comment: I was trying to understand why an `Element` array isn't returned in the case of `querySelectorAll`, which would have been in line with the output of `querySelector`. I have updated the question to reflect that

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi No. It doesn't answer my question. Have updated the question to make it even more clear

Answer (score 3):

For [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), on MDN, it says this:

> [it] returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements

So, the NodeList *does* contain a list of elements. The reason why this particular data structure is called a "NodeList" and not just an "ElementList" is because it can contain other types of nodes besides elements (such as a comment node, a text node, or a fragement node). `document.querySelectorAll()` will only return a NodeList with elements in it, but other functions/properties (such as the [.childNodes property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)) may generate nodeLists with other types of nodes.

One special property a nodeList has, that an array does not, is that a nodeList can be "live", which means it'll auto-update when there are changes to the DOM. This, however, does not apply to document.querySelectorAll() as querySelectorAll() will always return a non-live nodeList. As far as I can tell, they could have simply returned an element array instead, but maybe chose to return a nodeList in order to keep their browser APIs consistent with each other. Perhaps there's certain hidden optimizations they're able to do with the nodeList data structure.