# Alternative for document.getElelementById() for several IDs/elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that `document.getElementById()` won't work with several ids. So I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
```

But that also doesn't work at all. But if I use just the `document.getElementById()` it works with that one id. Here is my code:

```js
let toggle = () => {
  let circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
  let hidden = circle.getAttribute("hidden");

  if (hidden) {
    circle.removeAttribute("hidden");
  } else {
    circle.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, and to convert it to an array of elements, use `Array.from()`. this will return an array containing all of the elements with the class name `circle`

Here is an example, which changes each element with the `circle` class:

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')
const output = Array.from(items)

function change() {
  output.forEach(i => {
    var current = i.innerText.split(' ')
    current[1] = 'hate'
    current = current[0] + ' ' + current[1] + ' ' + current[2]
    i.innerText = current
  })
}
```

```html
<p class="circle"> I love cats! </p>
<p class="circle"> I love dogs! </p>
<p class="square">I love green!</p>
<p class="circle"> I love waffles! </p>
<p class="circle"> I love javascript! </p>
<p class="square">I love tea!</p>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I am very new to coding in general and I see that your method is properly working with your example but I can't implement it into my code, could you maybe explain to me how to do that, I tried but the implementation failed. I hope I am not asking fo too much :)

Comment: @Theo ```function toggle(){ let circle = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("circle")); let hidden = circle[0].hidden;    circle.forEach(item => {item.hidden = !hidden}) }```

Comment: Technically, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763707/13376511).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
const selectedIds = document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id12, #id3');

console.log(selectedIds);
//Will log [element#id1, element#id2, element#id3]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
for(const element of selectedIds){
//Do something with element
//Example:
element.style.color = "red"
}
```