What is the difference between nodelist and html collections and how do they differ from a normal array?
I am beginner at javascript so I need to understand the intricacies of the language to code better and to score between at the interviews I am learning javascript from Hritesh chowdhury sir
I watched a my course instructors video lectures which were really detailed by the way but I want some extra information about this topic and a little more clarity on this topic

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763707/1599011

MDN it. no one would know better.
