# Looping through element id's to generate screenshots with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, selectors-api

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. When running this in PhantomJS it just hangs with no response. It also doesn't show my console messages.

I have a website that has section blocks defined in div tags (templatemo_content). These div tags contain the same id. What I'm trying to accomplish is to loop through the website, located all of the templatemo_content div id's and generate screenshots of each templatemo_content div block.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('myWebpage', function() {

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };
  page.viewportSize = { width:1100, height:800 };
  console.log('open');

  window.setTimeout(function() { 
    var clipRects = page.evaluate(function(){
        return = document.querySelectorAll('#templatemo_content');//.getBoundingClientRect();
    });
    console.log('clipRect size = ' + clipRects.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < clipRects.length; ++i) {
        if (clipRects[i]) {
            console.log('element found');
            var clipRect = clipRects[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            page.clipRect = {
                top:    clipRect.top,
                left:   clipRect.left,
                width:  clipRect.width,
                height: clipRect.height
            };
            page.render('google.png');
        }
    }
    phantom.exit();
  }, 3000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time   
});
```

Again this hangs with not logs from the console. If I remove the for loop and change querySelectorAll to querySelector then it works for one of the div tags.

Any help would be great.

Comment: A starting point would be understanding that querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (Not an Array). Convert the nodelist to array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18129752/1670474.

Comment: Also you are overwriting and rendering page.clipRect and page.render on every loop iteration, which may be the issue, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really late answer, but: The problem is that you were calling the `getBoundingClientRect`-method outside of `page.evaluate`. When out of that context — the rendered DOM — `getBoundingClientRect` will not return anything useful. The solution:

```
var clipRects = page.evaluate(function(){
    var rects = [];
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#templatemo_content')
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
       rects.push(elements[i].getBoundingClientRect());
    }
    return rects;
});
```

This will run `getBoundingClientRect` while still in the correct context, and it will return an array of `DOMRect`'s that you'll be able to use. Perhaps something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < clipRects.length; ++i) {
   page.clipRect = clipRects[i];
   page.render('image' + i + '.png');
}
```