# Loop through elements and check children for class in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate over elements with the same class in order to see if within a specific element a button has a specific class. I understand how this would be done in jQuery however the project does not have jQuery, so this has to be done with vanilla JS...which I'm not as familiar with.

```
    let boardItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item--product");
    for (let i = 0; i < boardItems.length; i++) {
        if(boardItems.children.classList.contains('board-item-selected')){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

what I'd like is to get the index number of each item that does contain the class in the child.

Comment: `.children` is a `NodeList`, not a `Node`. It doesn’t have a `classList`. Consider using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): e.g. `boardItems.filter((item) => item.classList.contains("board-item-selected")).forEach((item) => console.log(item));`.

Comment: Um...if this is about collecting elements from the nested buttons by class or whatever (not sure of objective not clear) -- don't you think the HTML be included as well.  Please read on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. What I'm trying to achieve is that if there's 5 items with the same class, I want to know which of those five has a child div that has a specific class.  Is it 1 and 3, 2 and 5, just 4...1 2 3 4 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeList object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501433/nodelist-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @user1568811 HTML post it. I refuse to read dribble -- code presented properly is better than going on and on about something with no real context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `HTMLCollection` into an array of `HTMLElement` and parse the class list of each element.

```js
let htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("item--product");
let array = [].slice.call(htmlCollection)
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].classList.contains("board-item-selected")){
          console.log("The index of the board-item-selected: " + i)
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="item--product"></div>
<div class="item--product"></div>
<div class="item--product board-item-selected"></div>
<div class="item--product"></div>
<div class="item--product board-item-selected"></div>
<div class="item--product"></div>
<div class="item--product"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dalton.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the entire list not the array.

Try change line 3 to `if(boardItems[i].classList.contains('board-item-selected')) {`